# in Fat Free Framework, is it possible to display a missing key in a Template?

Tags: fat-free-framework

Working with Fat Free Framework template engine and translations using dictionary files.

In my template I have {{@_someNonTranslatedWord}} keys.

Currently FF just leaves the space emtpy when this key is missing.
Is there a way to make FF display the raw key instead of leaving the space empty?

I'd rather see something like:

```
"My {{@_someNonTranslatedWord}} is missing"
```

instead of

```
"My is missing"
```

So I can easily identify missing keys and add them. Possibly even auto-translate them when they're missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is possible with a little trick. You can use the framework var `PREFIX` to add a prefix to all language keys.. 
so when you set `PREFIX = ll.` in your config file, all keys in your language files are put into the array `ll` (ll = local language).

Now, in your template, you'll use `{{ @ll.welcome_headline }}` and you have all your keys separated nicely and don't conflict with the rest of your variables. And since you know, that all language keys are now within in `ll` array, you can exchange that array with an object, that implements ArrayAccess and adds some logic when accessing those keys.. here is a little helper I just wrote right now to test that behaviour, which works pretty well:

```
namespace Service;

class Dictionary extends \Magic {

    protected
        $lex = [],
        $prev_key,
        $f3;

    function __construct(array $lexicon, $prev_key = NULL) {
        $this->lex = $lexicon;
        $this->prev_key = $prev_key;
        $this->f3 = \Base::instance();
    }

    function exists($key) {
        $val=$this->f3->ref($key,FALSE,$this->lex);
        return isset($val);
    }

    function set($key,$val) {
        $ref=&$this->f3->ref($key, TRUE, $this->lex);
        $ref=$val;
        return $ref;
    }

    function &get($key) {
        $val=$this->f3->ref($key,FALSE, $this->lex);
        $current_key = ($this->prev_key?$this->prev_key.'.':'').$key;
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $val = new self($val, $current_key);
        } else {
            if (!$val) {
                // do something when language key is missing
                var_dump('missing language key: '.$current_key);
            } else {
                // track which language key was used
                var_dump('language key used: '.$current_key);
            }
        }
        return $val;
    }

    function clear($key) {
        // no clear
    }
}
```

To use that puppy, simply create the object, feed the lexicon entries in, and exchange the existing stupid array:

```
    $dict = new Service\Dictionary($fw->get('ll'));
    $fw->set('ll', $dict);
```

Do that before rendering the template, or using language keys in general. Everytime you access an existing or missing key, you can do something special in the `get` method.. maybe also translate them on the fly if you want to...

good luck ;)

Comment: Haha, I knew that you would come up with a hack.

Comment: Actually I already though about something like that for improved visual translating certain screens.. that question was one more reason now to build that thing :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is possible to return the original placeholder as F3 is converting templates to PHP code. Instead, you could enable the reporting of undefined PHP variables:

```php
error_reporting(error_reporting() | E_NOTICE);
```

On the one hand, this should be enough to get informed about missing variables. On the other hand, this doesn't enable you to use your auto-translation idea.

I am usually throwing exceptions on any kind of warning. The following snippet enables you to log undefined variables:

```php
set_error_handler(function($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) {
    if ($severity === E_NOTICE) {
        // Handle this issue, e.g. throw an exception or log the error silently.
        printf('Received this notice: %s in %s on line %s.', $message, $filename, $lineno);
        // throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $filename, $lineno);
    }
});
```

I can recommend the following snippet to upgrade all warnings to exceptions if you like to follow such a defensive/strict programming style: [Comment on `set_error_handler`()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#112881)

Comment: This works! It can be expanded to the actual function I needed: function index(){

        set_error_handler(function($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) {
            if ($severity === E_NOTICE) {
                $ex = explode(':',$message);
                if($ex[0]=='Undefined variable'){
                    //possibly add auto-translate here
                    echo "{{@".ltrim($ex[1],' ')."}}";
                }
            }
        });

        $this->f3->set('view', '/backend/home.html');
    }

Which replaces all instances on the home.html template with {{@_error}}

Answer (score 1):

create a function in your controller:

```
function t($key) {
  $f3 = \Base::instance();
  return $f3[$key] ?: ('{{@' . $key . '}}');
}
```

in the html, call the function:

```
"My {{ t('_someNonTranslatedWord') }} is missing"
```

will result

```
"My {{@_someNonTranslatedWord}} is missing"
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Rayne's comment I came up with this answer.

All my translation variables start with _ so I can distinguish them from other variables. This makes it possible to do this in my beforeRoute function:

```
 set_error_handler(function($severity, $message) {
        if ($severity === E_NOTICE) {
            $ex = explode(':',$message);

            $var = ltrim($ex[1],' ');


            if($ex[0]=='Undefined variable' && substr($var,0,1) =='_'){
                //possibly add auto-translate here
                echo "{{@".$var."}}";
            }
        }
    });
```

Now all missing variables starting with _ get printed out as {{@_missingVariable}}